# How to transform new data using sklearn.pipeline

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, tf-idf, multilabel-classification

I have created a pipeline with TfIdfVectorizer transformer and OnevsRestClassifier estimator and trained it on training data as follows

```
# Split data using train_test_split
print "Split data into train and test sets"
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data_x, data_y, test_size=0.33)

# transform matrix of plots into lists to pass to a TfidfVectorizer
train_x = [x[0].strip() for x in x_train.tolist()]
test_x = [x[0].strip() for x in x_test.tolist()]

# Pipeline fit and transform
print "Learn the model using train data"
model = text_clf.fit(train_x, y_train)

# Predict the test data
print "Predict the recipients on test data"
predictions = model.predict(test_x)
```

Now, I want to use the trained model to predict classes for new unlabeled data.
I tried this and got an error

```
# Read text from input
text = raw_input()
print "Input : ", text
new_data = text_clf.transform([text])
predict = model.predict(new_data)
```

This is the error. What Am I doing wrong?

```
AttributeError: 'OneVsRestClassifier' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `text_clf` and `model` are a pipeline as you have suggested, then no need to call transform and then predict. Only call

```
predictions = model.predict([text])
```

The pipeline will internally automatically transform the data into usable format (using `transform()` on intermediate transformers).

When you explicitly call `model.transform()`, the pipeline assumes that all the estimators inside the pipeline are having a transform() which is not the case here.